# How to Enable Hot Module Replacement with Webpack

Tags: theme-development, workflow, sass

I am using `@wordpress/scripts` to set up WordPress with Webpack in a Wordpress theme. The current configuration works fine and compiles the scss and js files from the `src` folder when I run `npm run start`. However it does not auto refresh the page when the files are updated. I am using this configuration to develop on my local LAMP installation. How I can do page auto reload when the files are updated? Here is the Webpack configuration I am currently using:

**webpack.config.js**

```
/**
 * External Dependencies
 */
const path = require( 'path' );
const FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin = require( 'webpack-fix-style-only-entries' );
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin' );

/**
 * WordPress Dependencies
 */
const defaultConfig = require( '@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config.js' );

module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    ...{
        entry: {
            main: path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'src/scss', 'main.scss' ),
            app: path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'src/js', 'app.js' ),
        },
    },
    plugins: [ new FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin(), new MiniCssExtractPlugin() ],
};
```

Comment: This is a bit more complex, so I'll just post a comment with some hints: Look up [webpack's DevServer, especially proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) and maybe take a look [how the Roots team solved it for their Sage theme](https://github.com/roots/sage), where it works for the whole theme - even PHP files.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out, seems like I am having a similar challenge now with WP theme development